# showing object attributes from active record relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, activerecord

I try to display ingredient.name after the line quantitiy.amount
but don't know how to retrieve the name from object

```
Ingredient.where(ingredient_id: quantity.ingredient_id)
```

which returns

```
#<Ingredient::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x8e30590>
```

Code

```
def show
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  @quantities = @recipe.quantities
  @ingredients = @recipe.ingredients
end

- @quantities.each do |quantity|
  %ul
    %li
      = quantity.amount
      = Ingredient.where(ingredient_id: quantity.ingredient_id)

class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quantities
  has_many :recipes, :through => :quantities
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you do so you already have the relation name in Quantity model, so you can access it direct:

```
= quantity.amount
= quantity.ingredient.name
```

and in case Quantity don't have a quantity so you should say the following to not raise an error:

```
= quantity.ingredient.try(:name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The assciations that I need in this case are

```
class Recipe
  has_many :quantities
end

class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Then in the controller, we use [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) to prevent doing queries in the loop

```
def show
  @recipe = Recipe.includes(quantities: :recipe).find(params[:id])
end
```

add a delegation in the quantity model

```
class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relations and stuff

  delegate :name, to: :ingredient, prefix: :true, allow_nil: :true
end
```

The view

```
- @recipe.quantities.each do |quantity|
  %ul
    %li
      = quantity.amount
      = quantity.ingredient_name
```